# Обращение к элементу загруженному через ajax

Tags: javascript

Как обратиться к элементу, который был добавлен в DOM через ajax, с помощью **чистого js**?
Везде нахожу только решение для jQuery через метод .on

Comment: Через `.on` разве не событие на родителя неизменяемого вешают таким образом? На чистом js аналогично следует поступать.

Comment: document.getElementById - если элемент в DOM, он будет возвращаться, неважно был ли он там всегда или недавно добавился

Comment: @EugeneBartosh а querySelector не работает таким образом? Использую именно его и ничего не находит

Comment: метод `on` это ивентхэндлеры, при чем тут вообще `querySelector` ? покажите свой код

Comment: Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему. То, что вы добавляете в Ajax и что хотите найти (нужен код в вопросе). jQuery - всего лишь библиотека JavaScript, облегчающая работу с ним. В таком виде на ваш вопрос нельзя дать однозначный объективный ответ.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych я использую querySelector для выбора элемента, на который хочу повесить событие через addEventListener. А этот элемент подгружается через ajax.

Comment: @gam1et22 есть предположение что вы это делаете до того, как отрабатывает ajax, но вы все-же приведите пример вашего кода

Answer (score 3):

Кода от вас не дождался, но вопрос в принципе я понял. Написал *сырой* код, чтобы показать пример того, что вы хотите. Есть две функции, которые висят на кликах кнопок:

- Функция `addElementToDOM` - имитация работы ajax, проще говоря, это
  просто добавление нового элемента в DOM, которого не было. Кнопка, которая лежит в документе под названием <kbd>Добавление элемента, которого не было</kbd>
- Функция `addEventListenerH1` - это функция, которая добавит слушателя
  `addEventListener` к нужному элементу (в нашем случае это `h1`). Кнопка, которая лежит в документе под названием <kbd>Добавить слушателя элементу, которого не было</kbd>

Теперь по шагам рассмотрим код детальнее, что он делает и для чего.

1. Просто запустим наш проект, у нас будет две кнопки и один скрытый блок `div`.
2. Имитация работы ajax. То есть мы добавим в наш документ новый элемент `h1`, которого не было ранее (типо ajax, но не ajax вовсе, главное смысл).
3. Добавим слушателя клика для `h1`. В чем смысл этого кода - через `querySelector` получим элемент (если добавим несколько одинаковых - вернет первый), если он есть, то добавим слушателя (в противном случае упадет ошибка, так как `querySelector` ничего не вернет, для этого и проверка `if (element)`)

Код достаточно простой для понимания, никакого jQuery, просто JavaScript, смотрите:

```js
function addEventListenerH1() {
  var element = document.querySelector('h1');
  if (element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('one').classList.remove("hidden");

      var el = document.getElementsByClassName('two')
      for (var index = 0; index < el.length; index++) {
        el[index].classList.add("hidden");
      }
    });
    alert('Слушатель добавлен!');
  } else {
    alert('Пока некого слушать! Элемента нет!');
  }
}

function addElementToDOM() {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1 class='two'>Привет!</h1>";
  divOne = document.getElementById("one");
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, divOne);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="hidden">One</div>
<input type="button" onclick="addElementToDOM();" value="Добавление элемента, которого не было" />
<button onclick="addEventListenerH1()">Добавить слушателя элементу, которого не было </button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Странно тогда почему у меня возвращался undefined. Когда вернусь к той задаче и найду ответ, отпишусь сюда

Comment: Denis Bubnov глянь мой вопрос подобный и подробный   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/780967/После-загрузки-контента-ajax-ом-на-сайт-dom-элементы-для-js-не-доступны

Comment: @Air глянул. Оберни код в main.js в код: `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {`, чтобы код выполнялся после готовности страницы. Есть еще совет вместо `const`, уж лучше `let` (я-то понимаю, что `const` аналогично `let` в плане внутренних свойств константы и про неизменяемость самой константы тоже в курсе). Не могу уделить достаточного временм на твой вопрос, вот написал свои первые мысли, сейчас занят просто.

Comment: Уже оборачивал...  Но результат тот же...