# После загрузки контента AJAX-ом на сайт DOM элементы для JS не доступны

Tags: javascript

Дамы и Господа, решил осложнить структуру сайта...

---

И после того, как вопрос отметили как дубликат, а я в дубликате не нашел решения, решил вопрос переформулировать. Тем более дали пару подсказок Особая благодарность `Дмытрык-у`.
Вопрос более подробно описан комментариями в коде

Есть такой ajax код: (в отдельном файле)

```
    function ajax(url, callback, data, request) {
    try {
        request = new(this.XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        request.open(data ? 'POST' : 'GET', url, 1);
        request.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            request.readyState > 3 && callback && callback(request.responseText, request);
        };
        request.send(data)
    } catch (e) {
        window.console && console.log(e);
    }
};
```

и вот такая структура  главного `index.html`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>On-Line</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./binary/image/icons/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./binary/fonts/aaafonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/master.css">
    <script src="./libs/jquery.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./js/ajax.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./js/arrayRadioChan.js" defer></script>
    <script src="./js/master.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./js/main.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

И далее я подгружаю  контент `ajax-ом` вот код

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const iDroot = document.getElementById('root');
    ajax('../pages/index.html', function(res) {
        iDroot.innerHTML = res;
        const blockRight = document.getElementById('blockRight');
        const blockLeft = document.getElementById('blockLeft');
        ajax('../pages/header/index.html', function(res) {
            blockRight.innerHTML = res;
            let h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
            console.log(h1); // как видно из скрина этот console.log  срабатывает
            h1.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log(h1); //  этот console.log не срабатывает но ошибки не выдает

            })
            // но если обернуть  h1.addEventListener('click',
            // в   setTimeout(function() {  то все работает
        })
        ajax('../pages/main/index.html', function(res) {
            blockLeft.innerHTML += res;
            let main = document.querySelector('main')
            console.log(main); // как видно из скрина этот console.log  срабатывает
            main.addEventListener('click', function() {
                console.log(main); //  этот console.log  срабатывает
            })
        })
        ajax('../pages/footer/index.html', function(res) {
            blockRight.innerHTML += res;
        })
    })
})
```

И есть еще другой файл `main.js` в котором

```
  setTimeout(function() {
       let menuWrapper = document.querySelector('menuWrapper')
       menuWrapper.addEventListener('click', function() {

           console.log(menuWrapper);
       })

   }, 500)
```

и если убрать обертку в виде `setTimeout` то эта функция тоже не работает.
Судя по сему, вопрос такой. Является ли в данном случае использование `setTimeout` костылем? Если да, то есть ли какой-нибудь более изящный вариант выйти из ситуации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72767/discussion-on-question-by-air----ajax----dom-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> blockRight.innerHTML += res;
> ```

Каждый раз когда ты изменяешь `innerHTML`, все существовавшие там dom-элементы уничтожаются, а вместо них создаются новые.

Соответственно, после выполнения этой строки ты подписан на клик по элементу, который уже не на странице.

Если нужно добавить кусок разметки к существующему элементу, то следует использовать

```
blockRight.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', res);
```

> ```
> ajax('../pages/header/index.html', function(res) {
>   blockRight.innerHTML = res;
>   ...
> })
>
>
> ajax('../pages/main/index.html', function(res) {
>   blockLeft.innerHTML += res;
>   ...
> })
>
> ajax('../pages/footer/index.html', function(res) {
>   blockRight.innerHTML += res;
> })
> ```

Это вообще неправильно. Нельзя ожидать, что ответы придут именно в таком порядке. Порядок этих вызовов может быть любым.

> ```
> function ajax(url, callback, data, request) {
>   try {
>     ...
>   } catch (e) {
> ```

Этот catch не ловит ничего полезного. В случае ошибки при ajax-запросе catch не вызовется.

Comment: Я тебя понял, благодарю....  Буду переписывать...  Пошел ковыряться))) Еще раз спасибо...